# How to replace the occurrences of pipe (|) without replacing the pipe used as a delimiter

Tags: linux, string, replace, pipe, delimiter

On Linux server, I have pipe-delimited files that have pipe (|) characters in some string columns. The files are pipe-delimited but the delimiter pipe is always in double quotes while pipes in the text/string can have any characters, space, etc around them. I would like to replace the non-delimiter pipes within the strings with a dash sign (-)

Here is an example:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
"1"|"This is my column 2 |Although there is pipe here, it is not a delimiter pipe."|"And this is my 3rd column '|" with a pipe followed by a double quote"|"|and finally this 4th column starts with a | that is not'|a delimiter
```

I have tried some SED and AWK commands but could not properly exclude the delimiters ("|") from the replacement in the strings.

I am trying to get an output like this:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
"1"|"This is my column 2 -Although there is pipe here, it is not a delimiter pipe."|"And this is my 3rd column '-" with a pipe followed by a double quote"|"-and finally this 4th column starts with a - that is not'-a delimiter
```

Comment: Take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Process the file with a programming language that has a CSV library, such as Python or PHP. It will respect the quotes. It's hard to do with sed or awk.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. I am trying to avoid that. These files are being piped into other  platforms via an Informatica pipeline. Informatica is trying to parse the strings and hits the pipes scattered in some of the text columns throws error b/c it pushes the fragments of the text into the next columns which happen to be numeric, thus error.

Comment: Do you want to fix the file before or after you feed it to the pipeline? If you're doing it before, just use a python script instead of awk script.

Comment: I really don't understand the file format you have presented.  At first I took it for a variation on CSV, but it's not.  Or at least not valid as such, for the double quotes do not match properly.

Comment: You're right @John Bolinger, it is confusing. I just updated the example adding 4th col and changing the text accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand either. It looks as if double-quotes are used to "escape" pipes in the second line. Contents of first column is `"1"`, second column `"This is my column 2 |Although there is pipe here, it is not a delimiter pipe."`, third column (supposedly) `"And this is my 3rd column '|" with a pipe followed by a double quote"|"`. But fourth column `and finally this 4th column starts with a | that is not'|a delimiter` doesn't make sense ...

Comment: Perhaps a simpler example: The following has 5 columns shown in the header row (delimited with pipes) that match 5 occurrences of "|" (w/quotes) as delimiters in the data row. The rest of the pipes (|) in the text columns have different characters around them. I want those (non-delimiter) pipes in the text fields to be replaced with a character (like dash, underscore, space) that does not cause parsing problem:
----------
col1|col2|col3|cpl4|col5

"1"|"text| text"|"moretext'|"w/quotes."|""|,text "|"#5|-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways I can think of is to replace "|" with some special character (## in this case) and replace all occurances of | with - then replace back ## with "|"

```
cat file.txt | sed -e "s/\"|\"/##/g" | tr "|" - | sed -e "s/##/\"|\"/g"
```

Output  -

```
col1-col2-col3
"1"|"This is my column 2 -Although there is pipe here, it is not a delimiter pipe."|"And this is my 2nd column '-" with a pipe followed by a double quote"|"-and finally this 3rd column starts with a - that is not'-a delimiter
```

Comment: Thank you @Anant for the solution. This does the trick. However, there is a degree of risk in temporarily using any set of characters as the text fields in the files are long and they have all kinds of combinations of characters. But I will implement it for now. as a solution. Thank you.

Comment: I was thinking of and have tried to find a solution that just excludes all occurrences of "|" (w/quotes) and replaces all other occurrences of pipe with a dash (or with nothing, or w/something harmless)